# Display output of `time` only if command after `time` was successful

Tags: command-line, time, exit-status

I want the output of the `time` command to be shown only if the command, which has been passed to `time` was successful. Something like this:

```
( time wget -pq --delete-after https://www.example.com ) 2>&1 || echo fail
```

The problem is, that if `wget` fails, I still receive the output from `time` (which is somewhere logical, as it measures how long it took for the command to fail anyway). My goal is to save the output to a variable and either have `0m0.100s` or `fail` in my variable. Does anyone has an idea how I could do this in a decent manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$ if var=$( { time true; } 2>&1 ); then echo "$var"; else echo fail; fi

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

---

```
$ if var=$( { time false; } 2>&1 ); then echo "$var"; else echo fail; fi
fail
```

Comment: `var=$( { time sleep 1; } 2>&1 )` should work with Bash, ksh and zsh (though `time true` doesn't print anything in my zsh, hmm)

Comment: @ilkkachu Brief look through `zsh` [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) seems to suggest there's `times` but no `time`, though there is an [extension for that](https://github.com/popstas/zsh-command-time) apparently.  Maybe `/bin/time` is better choice if portability is a concern ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, `type time` says `time is a reserved word` on my zsh. But doing `time foo` where `foo` is a builtin doesn't print anything from `time`... `time true` is silent, but `time /bin/true` prints the (near-zero) time it took to run `/bin/true`.